# jQuery selector for immediate grand children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a better way for writing the following traversal using `selectors`?

```
$table.children('tbody').children('tr');
```

I want to filter immediate grand children, without including further descendants (table inside table).

In jQuery documentation `$table.find('> tbody > tr')` is marked as deprecated.

**Update**
I'm looking for a selector that is faster or equivalent to the above method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative selector I could suggest only the following. Besides, I doubt if there is something faster than simple DOM `el.childNodes` iteration which is represented by `children()` method.

```
$table.find("tr:not(tr tr)")​​​​​​​​;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mZppb/

Comment: will this be faster than `children().children()` or at least equivalent? Something tells me this will be slower, because it will find all the elements before filtering out the unwanted descendants.

Comment: @JoyceBabu No, it won't be faster.

Answer (score 1):

If it is immediate use:

```
$('table > tbody > tr');
```

Comment: That's what OP is using.  Also, he mentioned that it's now deprecated.  No idea why they would deprecate an actual css selector but it appears to be true: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: @JosephMarikle It's only deprecated if used with a context (i.e. with `find`) where there is no initial element (so `> tbody > tr`). This is fine, albeit probably not useful to the OP.

Comment: @Rick_Donohoe I can't use that, because there is a context `$table`.